# Is it possible to make the insert command from existing table data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have table which has a few data.

```
  name score
1 AAA  100
2 BBB  98
3 CCC  85
```

Now I want to make the insert sentence such as

```
 insert into pepolescore(name,score) VALUE("CCC",85)
```

automatically.

Is there any command to do this or any function ? by mysql commandline or `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, ...) SELECT ... FROM existingtable` will use the result of the `SELECT` query as the data to insert.

Comment: Thank you veyr much for your reply, but I want to insert data to another database (but same table structure)

Comment: `INSERT into db1.tablename SELECT * from db2.tablename`

Comment: AH, I see. I can use another database name directly.

Comment: AH sorry, not another database, another server...So I need to make plain insert sentence.

Comment: Use `mysqldump` to make a dump of the table from one server. Then use that to load into the other server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL queries can address another schema on the same MySQL Server instance by using qualified table names. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

But this does not work if the tables are on separate MySQL Servers. A given SQL query can only address schemas on the same server.

Here are a few workarounds:

1. Use mysqldump to export data from one table and then use mysql to import it to the other table on the other instance. You need to be careful not to let mysqldump output the `DROP TABLE` command, so read about the options here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html
2. MySQL supports a table engine called FEDERATED, where a table can function as a sort of proxy to a table on another MySQL Server. Then you can use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax as if the tables were co-located on the same MySQL Server. The Federated engine has limitations, so read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html and its subsections to learn more.
3. Use a community tool such as `pt-archiver` to copy data from one MySQL instance to the other. Read the manual to learn more: https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-archiver.html
4. Write your own custom code in a client application. Create two connections, one for each MySQL Server. Fetch query results from the first server, and store the resulting rows in variables in your application. Then use these rows as the tuples to insert using the second connection to the other MySQL Server. This involves writing more code, but you get a lot of flexibility.

Comment: I see. it might be complicated and takes time to learn for me. but thankyou very much